# Return The Value back as WebCameraId

Tags: vb.net

```
Try
    For Each Camera As WebCameraId In frmMain.wcc.GetVideoCaptureDevices

        If cbCamera.SelectedItem = Camera.GetHashCode Then
            txtCamName.Text = Camera.Name
        End If
    Next

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

How can I return the value back to webcameraId?

Comment: Which variable are you trying to return? and take the time to take the [tour] and read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command solved the problem

```
Try
        Dim CamId As New List(Of WebCameraId)(frmMain.wcc.GetVideoCaptureDevices())
        For Each Camera As WebCameraId In frmMain.wcc.GetVideoCaptureDevices

            If cbCamera.SelectedItem = Camera.GetHashCode Then
                txtCamName.Text = Camera.Name
                txtCamIndex.Text = CamId.IndexOf(Camera)
                frmMain.wcc.StartCapture(CamId(txtCamIndex.Text))
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error 0x03102090Cam" & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

it returns the value of Camera into CamId. I can now able to use StartCapture from SQL database.